# Infinite Loop with useEffect - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a problem when using the useEffect hook, it is generating an infinite loop.

I have a list that is loaded as soon as the page is assembled and should also be updated when a new record is found in "developers" state.

See the code:

```
  const [developers, setDevelopers] = useState<DevelopersData[]>([]);

  const getDevelopers = async () => {
    await api.get('/developers').then(response => {
      setDevelopers(response.data);
    });
  };
  
  // This way, the loop does not happen
  useEffect(() => {
    getDevelopers();
  }, []);

  // This way, infinte loop
  useEffect(() => {
    getDevelopers();
  }, [developers]);

  console.log(developers)
```

If I remove the developer dependency on the second parameter of useEffect, the loop does not happen, however, the list is not updated when a new record is found. If I insert "developers" in the second parameter of useEffect, the list is updated automatically, however, it goes into an infinite loop.

What am I doing wrong?

complete code (with component): https://gist.github.com/fredarend/c571d2b2fd88c734997a757bac6ab766

Print:
[image]

Comment: You mention "the list is not updated when a new record is found" - found where?

Comment: useEffect call => getDeveloppers  that change the developpers then use effect trigger , then repeat

Comment: @AKX See the image I added to the post.

I register a developer in the form on the left, the getDevelopers function, search for registered developers in the database, I would like the list to be updated as soon as a new dev is registered.

This works, however, only if I use the developers state as a second parameter, but then the loop happens.

Comment: @Fred Thank you for the clarification. The fact that there is a form that modifies `developers` locally is crucial here. I'll amend my answer...

Comment: @Fred Alright, please see my edit. :)

Comment: @Fred fyi the term for what you are doing is basically Optimistic UI/Optimistic response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependencies for `useEffect` use reference equality, not deep equality. (If you need deep equality comparison for some reason, take a look at [`use-deep-compare-effect`](https://github.com/kentcdodds/use-deep-compare-effect).)

The API call always returns a new array object, so its reference/identity is not the same as it was earlier, triggering `useEffect` to fire the effect again, etc.

Given that nothing else ever calls `setDevelopers`, i.e. there's no way for `developers` to change unless it was from the API call triggered by the effect, there's really no actual need to have `developers` as a dependency to `useEffect`; you can just have an empty array as deps: `useEffect(() => ..., [])`. The effect will only be called exactly once.

**EDIT:** Following the comment clarification,

> I register a developer in the form on the left [...] I would like the list to be updated as soon as a new dev is registered.

This is one way to do things:

The idea here is that `developers` is only ever automatically loaded on component mount. When the user adds a new developer via the `AddDeveloperForm`, we opportunistically update the local `developers` state while we're posting the new developer to the backend. Whether or not posting fails, we reload the list from the backend to ensure we have the freshest *real* state.

```
const DevList: React.FC = () => {
  const [developers, setDevelopers] = useState<DevelopersData[]>([]);

  const getDevelopers = useCallback(async () => {
    await api.get("/developers").then((response) => {
      setDevelopers(response.data);
    });
  }, [setDevelopers]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getDevelopers();
  }, [getDevelopers]);

  const onAddDeveloper = useCallback(
    async (newDeveloper) => {
      const newDevelopers = developers.concat([newDeveloper]);
      setDevelopers(newDevelopers);
      try {
        await postNewDeveloperToAPI(newDeveloper); // TODO: Implement me
      } catch (e) {
        alert("Oops, failed posting developer information...");
      }
      getDevelopers();
    },
    [developers],
  );

  return (
    <>
      <AddDeveloperForm onAddDeveloper={onAddDeveloper} />
      <DeveloperList developers={developers} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Now I understand the concept!
I will study more about the Hooks, they are very interesting.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `getDevelopers` function, calls your `setDevelopers` function, which updates your `developers` variable. When your `developers` variable is updated, it triggers the `useEffect` function

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getDevelopers();
  }, [developers]);
```

because `developers` is one of the dependencies passed to it and the process starts over.

Every time a variable within the array, which is passed as the second argument to useEffect, gets updated, the `useEffect` function gets triggered

Answer (score 0):

Use an empty array `[]` in the second parameter of the useEffect.
This causes the code inside to run only on mount of the parent component.

```
useEffect(() => {
    getDevelopers();
  }, []);
```

Comment: The code doesn't run on unmount. If you return a function from `useEffect`, that would be run on unmount.